# How to show Facebook like pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I  want to show facebook like box pop up when someone visit my website. I know how to show pop up, i am trying to figure out how would i know if somebody has already liked my page and prevent facebook pop-up showing up. Ive seen this is in few websites and want to add in mine.

Thanx alot.

Comment: you would like a pop up like a light box eg: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ click in the picture to see the effect

Comment: Yes. When a user enter my site asking to like my facebook page but i want this to be hidden if user has already liked my page.

Comment: you will need build a aplication give one look at https://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user has liked you page you will need to use the [graph facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/)